# Protractor e2e: extracting a string and assigning it to a var

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, promise, protractor

I'm using Protractor and TypeScript to drive e2e regression

**element**

```
<strong _ngcontent-jwu-49="" data-protractor="StreamId">11107</strong>'
```

**case** 
I need to extract ID from an element and construct a URL out of a string and ID

no matter what I do, a promise is not getting resolved

**here is what I've tried**

```
function getStreamId() {
    //browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    var streamIdElement = $$("[data-protractor='StreamId']")
    var streamId = streamIdElement.getText().then(
function(text){

browser.get('https://URL/page/'+text); 
      console.log(streamId)
    })
```

still a promise

and

```
browser.executeScript("var text = document.querySelectorAll('[data-
protractor='StreamId']').innerHtml").then(function(text)
{console.log(text);});
```

> fails WebDriverError: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception:
>   SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

My question is 2 part one:

1. what is the best practice in protractor if a value needs to be extracted and interacted with later
2. is it even possible to resolve a promise into a string (not to read it in the log with `.then(function(text){console.log(text)})`, so I can assign it to a variable and use it later on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt is actually quite close to the end result. You've located the element, called the `getText()` and resolved the promise.

*Make the function return a promise and resolve once you need an actual value*:

```
function getStreamId() {
    var streamIdElement = $$("[data-protractor='StreamId']")
    return streamIdElement.getText();
}

getStreamId().then(function(streamId) {          
    browser.get('https://URL/page/'+streamId); 
    console.log(streamId);
});
```

Comment: sorry for going silent on you. Thank you for your answer I'll try this solution this week and report back.